# Free registry removal tool?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-registry

Are there any **free 'registry items' removal** tools for Windows 7?

An example use case would be if I uninstalled a program and then wanted to delete any entries that contain the program name.

Comment: If you want to delete the entire registry you'll have to get rid of Windows, installing another operating system should take care of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RevoUninstaller will perform the uninstall and then search the registry and filesystem for left over files and settings and allow you to do further cleanup. It's simple, straightforward, easy, and there's a free version.

Also, CCleaner has a pretty decent registry cleaner that's probably the best one out there right now. It's free as well.

UPDATE:

Actually yes, RevoUninstaller has a [free version](http://www.revouninstaller.com/start_freeware_download.html).

But if you have other things against RevoUninstaller (it's just the one I have experience with), there is also [Advanced Uninstaller](http://www.iobit.com/advanceduninstaller.html), which is freeware, and I've heard others recommend it.

Comment: But RevoUninstaller isn't free. And not sure if CCleaner (my favourite tool) does what I asked for.

Comment: Yes it is Free...http://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html

Answer (score 1):

The best registry scanner I've ever used is from MaceCraft.  The engine is so much faster then the others and they finally released something fully freeware. If you want something more suite-like They do have 30-day versions of the great PowerTools.

However I just tried the PowerTools Lite, and its essentially just the reg cleaning engine.  It's never botched my system, and I've used some version of the MaceCraft engine for close to a decade.

It is significantly better than the other freeware cleaners, I remember trying.

Here is the link for the Freeware cleaner, 
http://www.macecraft.com/powertoolslite2011/

Answer (score 0):

[Nirsoft's RegScanner (freeware)](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/regscanner.html) will let you search for and mass-delete registry entries a lot quicker and easier than `regedt32.exe`, I've used it to clean up after a few uninstallers.